# .NET Reactor way to fail signing process when licence is not found

Tags: continuous-integration, net-reactor

I've added a new hard drive to my build server, unfortunately it caused license expiration on .Net reactor.

My problem is that I need a way to fail reactor signing process when situation like this take place. Unfortuantelly reactor still signed our assemblies with success message and without any sign of failure.

It was during runtime when we got error message which says: "This assembly is protected by unregistered version of Ezriz's .NET Reactor! ".

Is there any way that I can parametrize console app so that it fails when license is not found? I have trouble finding such opition in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a not documented parameter:

If you call .NET Reactor with the '-licensed' parameter it will return the return code 101 in case no valid license was found. For example:

dotNET_Reactor.exe  -licensed -project "C:\yourproject.nrproj"

This way you could detect if the build failed without running your protected software.